# Windows touchpad-like smooth mouse scrolling

Tags: mouse, windows-11, touchpad, scrolling

Is there a way to enable "real" smooth scrolling system-wide in Windows (11)? I just got Logitech MX Master 3s with a free rotating scroll wheel, but so far smooth scrolling only works in Firefox. I am not talking about animating the scrolling of n lines, but actually being able to scroll individual pixels. I know the mouse is capable, as it works in Firefox, and I know pretty much all software is capable, as this is a normal behavior when scrolling with a trackpad. So there should be a way to enable smooth scrolling for a normal mouse?